# Publish command result of command handler through ConsumeContext --Masstransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit, rabbitmq-exchange

I have configured a webapi controller for masstransit . something like this .

```
_busControl = MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
            {
                x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>{ });
            });
            _busControl.Start();
```

and the console application is my server which is listening to my commmands / events --

```
 var BusControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
             {
                 var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
                {
                    //h.Username("guest");
                    //h.Password("guest");
                });

                 cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "create_product_queue", config => config.Consumer<CreateInventoryProductItemHandler>());
                 cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "ProductItemCreatedEvent", config => config.Handler<ProductItemCreatedEvent>(async context => await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Product Item Id -----{context.Message.ProductItemId} "))); <---- this never gets executed . 
             });
            BusControl.Start();
```

And the controller action is something like -

```
[HttpPost("product")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Product Product)
        {
            var endpoint = await Startup.Bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/create_product_queue"));
            await endpoint.Send<CreateInventoryProductItem>(new
            {
                ProductName = Product.ProductName,
                PartNumber = Product.PartNumber,
                ManufactureDate = Product.ManufacturedDate
            });
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted);
        }
```

and the handler is --

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateInventoryProductItem> context)
        {
            CreateInventoryProductItem Command = context.Message;
            Product Product = await Context.SaveAsync(new Product(Command.ProductName
                , Command.PartNumber
                , Command.ManufacturedDate));
            await context.Publish<ProductItemCreatedEvent>(Product.Id); <--- problem area

        }
```

Now my scenario is .

1. Create a command object .
2. Get the product Id from the Entity framework `Context.SaveAsync()` method which has been newly created.
3. Publish the ProductId to the bus so that other listeners can listen to this product Id and act accordingly .

   I am trying to figure out the best pattern to be applied in this case .

Now the problem starts with --  `await context.Publish<ProductItemCreatedEvent>(Product.Id);` this line . It tries to publish again and again to the same queue infinitely . As a result same Product object is getting inserted hundreds of times ( pretty lame I know cause no unique constraint but thats not the question here ), and what happens is that my command handler inspite of being strongly typed its getting executed indefinitely . How to get rid of this situation . I am pretty new to masstransit concepts.

so can someone shed some light why is this happening .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you need to pass an object to the `Publish` overload that you are using:

```
await context.Publish<ProductItemCreatedEvent>(Product.Id);
```

If the `ProductItemCreatedEvent` included two properties, `Id` and `Description`, you would create an anonymous object to initialize the interface:

```
await context.Publish<ProductItemCreatedEvent>(new
{
    Id = Product.Id,
    Description = Product.Description,
});
```

This way, an object with properties is passed which can initiate the dynamically generated backing class for the event interface.

Comment: I realized it a little late about thata . Thanks for responding to that .